# Writing to renderbuffer AND display with OpenGL with single rendercall

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Is there a way to render to both, a renderbuffer and to the display without have to call multiple times the draw function? I wanted someting like this:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE2D, tbo, 0);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GLenum* attachments[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, ...} //with the second I want to render to screen which would have the same value like the first
glDrawBuffer(2, attachments);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

So I can use what I drawed in the same time as a texture for another rendercall. I could just write

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

but this would require to draw the scene again, which would be slow. Another solution would be just to draw the framebuffer, but I thought there would be a smarter solution.

Comment: Short answer: No. But, use [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) to copy from one framebuffer to another. Of course the data have to be copied, but there is no need to render the scene again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy a frame buffer to another one using  [`glBlitFramebuffer()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml).

Something like:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBlitFramebuffer(
    0, 0, fboWidth, fboHeight,
    0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight,
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

should do the trick.